# Bash multiprocessing CPU issue

Tags: bash, multiprocessing, cpu

I execute the code below with BASH. After a while CPU is getting %60-%70 and then full.
What can cause this and how can I fix it. I am using freeBSD 9.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -bm
startjob() {
  if [ $count -lt $total_jobs ]; then
   echo $started ve $count
   curl -o /depo/$count".txt" -s "http://api.domain.com/$count"  &
   count=$(($count+1))
  fi
}
max_parallel=200
total_jobs=100000

trap 'startjob' SIGCHLD
count=0
started=0
while [ $started -lt $max_parallel ]; do
   startjob || break;
     sleep 0.01;
  started=$(($started+1))
 #  echo $started
done
wait
```

Comment: How many jobs are running when the system is that loaded? Are you simply running too many jobs in parallel here?

Comment: May I recommend `GNU Parallel`...

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU skyrockets because you run too many processes at once, and use [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) (`sleep 0.01` while you spawn 200 processes at once? it's surely going to lag!)

If I were you I'd use GNU/parallel like this:

```
cat listfile.txt | parallel curl -O
```

It takes care of things at much lower level and thus should consume less CPU. Apparently it's available on FreeBSD, too: https://www.freebsd.org/ports/parallel.html

Comment: i think parallel is perl . and result is ; perl /usr/local/bin/parallel curl -o /depo/blabla txt. cpu X 2 now :))